# I'm not able to get root permission within my python program

Tags: python, sudo

I am new to Python and keep getting the same *permission denied* error, when I execute the following statement:

```
>>> os.chdir('/root')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root'
```

Comment: you have to start the script by root.

Comment: you need to start your script with sudo: `$ sudo python script.py` (on a debian-like system); otherwise as root: `# python script.py`.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: If your understanding of U*x privileges is very limited, you **should not** be `root`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the permissions on the `/root` directory are set so that non-root users cannot access it.

So this is not really a program error nor a Python error, but a system configuration issue. One can debate the necessity of restricting the permissions like that. On my FreeBSD system you can read and access `/root`; there are hardly any files there anyway. But maybe it contains sensitive data or programs on your system.

So you basically have *two* options;

- using `sudo` or
- changing the permissions on `/root`.

Which of the two is "best" depends on what you want to do and what is in the root directory.

But since the `root` user has access to *everything*, it is possible to accidentally do a lot of damage when running as `root`.
So in general it is recommended not to execute scripts as root, unless it is absolutely necessary.

BTW, it is possible to handle with this situation by testing for access first;

```
import os

if os.access('/root', os.R_OK|os.X_OK):
    os.chdir('/root')
    # whatever else you were going to do
else:
    print 'Insufficient access to /root'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not running the program with the appropriate permissions.

Run the programs as the root user, this will grant you the appropriate permissions.

You can do this with

```
sudo python script.py
```

of if you don't have sudo

```
su - root -c "python script.py"
```

for more info http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/